# Using Focuspoint with eager loading

Tags: image-transforms, image, eager-loading, plugin-imager, plugin-focuspoint

I'm using eager loading for retrieving some images for my gallery:

```
{% set employments = craft.entries({ section: 'employments', with: ['photo] }) %}
```

This works fine and I can see all images on my page.

I'm using focuspoint (https://github.com/smcyr/Craft-FocusPoint) with imager for resizing the images. I've set a different focuspoint for every image.
But whenever I try to get the focuspoints of a image:
`photo[0].focusPctX`, all images have the same focuspoints (50).

Whenever I try to retrieve the images without the eager loading function, it works fine.

I've created a new issue @focuspoint github.

Is there someone that had the same problem, or has a solution for this?

Comment: same issue here. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Created a answer for you ;)

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look at the other focalpoint plugin then, as use it on every image. So definitely need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue too and had landed on this thread (and another similar one). I was able to piece together a solution using the modify elements query method. I wrote a pull request that got merged, so lazy-loading works with this plugin as of version 1.1.4.

Answer (score 4):

After some research I found out that this problem has no simple solution (unfortunately). Check https://github.com/smcyr/Craft-FocusPoint/issues/10.

A solution would be not to use eager loading (obvious). Another solution could be using Craft3 (no plugin needed).

The solution I used was Focal Point (https://github.com/aelvan/FocalPointField-Craft). Focal Point is a tool that can be used with Eager Loading. Focal Point creates a focus point on every asset, that means not on every asset field.