# Eager Loading breaking focus point

Tags: eager-loading, plugin-focuspoint

I’m trying to cut down the amount of database queries on the homepage of a site I’m working on, and am attempting to do some eager loading of an asset set in a supertable field. However, although the queries drop, the focus point no longer works when I do, so I think it’s not setup right. Can anyone explain what I’m doing wrong please?

```html
{% set mainCarousel = entry.mainCarousel.find({
 with: [
 'carouselImage'
 ]
}) %}
{% for row in mainCarousel %}
{% set image = row.carouselImage[0] ?? null %}
{% set transformedImages = craft.imager.transformImage(image,
  [
      { width: 1920, ratio: 3/1, jpegQuality: 60 },
      { width: 1440, ratio: 3/1 },
      { width: 1024, ratio: 3/1 },
      { width: 750, ratio: 4/3, jpegQuality: 60 },
  ],
  {
      format: 'jpg',
      allowUpscale: false,
      mode: 'crop',
      jpegQuality: 80,
      position: image.focusPctX ~ '% ' ~ image.focusPctY ~ '%',
      interlace: true
  }
) %}
<div>
 {% if image | length %}
 <picture>
   <source srcset="{{ craft.imager.srcset(transformedImages) }}">
   <img class=""
        data-lazy="{{ siteUrl }}assets/placeholder.png"
        src="{{ transformedImages[1].url }}"
        sizes="100vw"
        alt="{{ image.title }}">
 </picture>
 {% endif %}
 <div class="overlay-box">
   <h2>{{ row.heading }}</h2>
   <p>{{ row.text }}</p>
   {% set button = row.button %}
   {% if button|length %}<a class="readmore" href="{{ button.getUrl() }}">View Project</a>{% endif %}
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered in another thread here: [enter link description here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18608/using-focuspoint-with-eager-loading?noredirect=1#comment29323_18608), but basically you have to use another focal point plugin called [FocalPointField-Craft](https://github.com/aelvan/FocalPointField-Craft) which then works with eager loading. And I've found also uses a lot less database queries than the other plugin too.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too and had landed on this thread. I was able to piece together a solution using the modify elements query method. I wrote a pull request that got merged, so lazy-loading works with this plugin as of version [1.1.4](https://github.com/smcyr/Craft-FocusPoint/commit/5b5f2c0bf416cfe98ae2332d1c0a62334ae4b69f).